# Implicit declaration of function 'fopen_s' is invalid in C99

Tags: c

I am writing a function in C for class and we were given this as a starter to the assignment. I have literally copied and pasted however I am gettin and error that reads "Implicit declaration of function 'fopen_s' is invalid in C99" and "Use of undeclared identifier 'fp'"

```
#include <stdio.h>

int compare(void);

int main(void) {
int i;

fopen_s(&fp, "largeSmallLab.txt", "w");

for (i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
    compare();
}

fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `fopen_s` is Windows stuff, are you compiling with Visual Studio? Otherwise the compiler is complaining about a non existing function and in this case you should use plain `fopen`.

Comment: `_s` functions are an optional part of the C99 standard. Generally only Microsoft compilers implement them.

Comment: No I am running this on Mac (XCode)

Comment: So i can just run fopen() like normal?

Comment: @sinafarheidar12 of course, you can use `fopen`, but always check his result.